# How to support API levels < 14?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-2.2-froyo

As it is known, the minimum API level for using the Android support library is 14 now. I would like to release a new version of my app (currently minSdk 15 and targetSdk 27) to support API < 14 (down to Froyo at the minimum if possible). Why you ask? I do not plan to keep supporting for these old system versions, but rather just to fix one critical bug to help the numerous users I have on these platforms - a bug which will actually help them export their data to newer versions.

When changing the minSdk to 10 I get the following error:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller
>   than version 14 declared in library
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1] as the library might be
>   using APIs not available in 10     Suggestion: use a compatible library
>   with a minSdk of at most 10,      or increase this project's minSdk
>   version to at least 14,       or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
>   (may lead to runtime failures)

Anyway, here is what I considered - or a combination of the following:

1. Using an old support library version 25.4.0 that work with minSdk < 14 as an "oldApi" product flavor (and the new support library version for the normal release flavor)
2. Use the original methods from the old platform versions without support libraries at all and then release an APK with minSdk X and maxSdk 14
3. Multi APK release

What is the best approach? Is there an easier way?

Comment: If it is to fix one critical bug why you should update or change the support libraries? Just fix the code as it is.

Comment: I cannot use minSdk < 14 currently. I already fixed the bug long ago for mindSdk > 15

Comment: I can't understand. If your current app supports these devices with minSdk<14 you should just have the code with minSdk<14.

Comment: I've updated the app after three years of inactivity. Back then the support libraries worked and the minSdk was 9.

Comment: Ok, then just use the same code without updating the support libraries and only fix the code

Comment: So keep the same release for all versions? As long as I check invalid (too new) method calls at runtime? Speaking of which, will Lint let me know about these calls when compiling? for example a post-Lollipop method on a device running pre-Lollipop system

Comment: Just do different flavors with different checks and different dependencies

Comment: Using new versions of support library under API 14 will crash with NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supporting my libraries started from API 9 (yes, Android 2.3 and up. In 2020. It's some kind of challenge for me). I've tested it with API 4 (!) and all is working great, but Material Design supporting since API 9, so I'm using the 25.4.0 version of Support Design library too which started from API 9. It's most prefer solution for me, because it allows to get only one apk for API 9-30 with Material Design which working great from API 9 to API 30, because 25.4.0 was released in June 2017 and base methods are not changing even in API 30. BTW I don't see any seriosly updated in the new support library versions to raise my min API version to 14 and of course up.