# How to use different dependencies in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, backwards-compatibility

(related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326293/how-to-support-api-levels-14))

I want to publish a one time update for my app for minSdk < 14 (compared to the current minSdk = 15. I am considering creating two flavors of my app - one that supports API levels lower than 14 with android support library **25.4.0**, and for API level 14 and newer that uses the latest support library 27.1.1, which only support API 14 and above.

Can the `dependencies` section of the build.gradle support different packages imports for different flavors?

My first try looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    flavorDimensions "standard", "oldApi"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 37
        versionName "2.1.3"
        applicationId "org.app"
    }

    productFlavors {
        standard {
            dimension "standard"
            targetSdkVersion 27
            minSdkVersion 15
        }

        oldApi {
            dimension "oldApi"
            versionNameSuffix "X" //for old devices
            targetSdkVersion 14
            minSdkVersion 8
            maxSdkVersion 14
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {...}
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {...}
        debug {...}
    }
}

dependencies {
    standardImplementation project(path: ':MyappLibrary', configuration: 'standard')
    oldApiImplementation project(path: ':MyappLibrary', configuration: 'oldApi')
}
```

and:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    flavorDimensions "standard", "oldApi"

    productFlavors {
        standard {
            dimension "standard"
        }

        oldApi {
            dimension "oldApi"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.6'
    standardApi "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$package_version"
    standardApi "com.android.support:support-v4:$package_version"
    oldApiApi 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
}
```

Errors (note the bolded parts):

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@**standardOldApiDebug**/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   project :MyappLibrary.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@**standardOldApiDebugAndroidTest**/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve project :MyappLibrary. Open File Show Details

Answer (score 0):

> Can the `dependencies` section of the build.gradle support different packages imports for different flavors?

You can specify:

```
productFlavors {
        f1 {
           //..
        }
        f2 {
           //..
        }
   }

dependencies{         
    f1Implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.2.1'
    f2Implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27..1'
}
```

More [info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#dependencies).

Comment: I can't find how to do the separated dependencies calls in that link.

Comment: The link illustrates how to use different flavors. What is not clear? Check also the answer. Just use <nameFlavor>Implementation xxxx to use different dependencies

Comment: I didn't say your answer wasn't clear... just that I couldn't find an example specifically how to do the dependencies part of the product flavors. If I understand you correctly, I shouldn't put a space between the flavor name and the "Implementation" syntax?

Comment: Also, how do I input dependencies and other tasks that apply to all flavors?

Comment: Yes without space (of course it is the same for `compile` and `api` DSL). To use a dependency for all flavors/build types just use the simple `implementation` or `api` dsl without prefix.

Comment: ok I missed the part where you have the capitalize the first letter (I used api instead of Api) as per https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Comment: Added code with flavors and dimensions. I forgot to mention I'm using a library module which complicates things

Comment: @PIXP Check this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#variant_dependencies.In any case this is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question